# reverse grip lateral pulldown

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding

when trying to workout the lats/ lower-lats, does using a reverse grip actually provide any utility in honing in on the lower lats?  Or is the reverse grip just a strategy to have a stronger grip?

Also, for mid-lower lat workouts, is an extremely narrow grip useful, or should you use shoulder width?  Or, does it depend on your physique?

Answer (score 1):

In doing lat pulldowns when using a reverse grip (palms up I presume) as long as you are focusing on not pulling down with your biceps and focusing on your lats. You are using more of your lower lats. WHY? well if you think about it, with a reverse grip it allows your elbows to be closer to your body allowing for that bigger contraction in your lower/mid lat range.